# Merge two images with overlapping pixels having weighted rgb value based on opacity

Tags: python, merge, rgb, opacity

I have two images with transparent backgrounds. These images are masks obtained from an image of a surface:

[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

I'm trying to merge them, such that pixels that overlap have their rgb value set according to the opacity of the pixel in the first image and the opacity of the pixel in the second image.

For example, if the overlapping pixels have values (90, 89, 85, 226) and (117, 109, 93, 195), then more weight should be given to the first pixel when the rgb value is set for that pixel in the merged image.

Any ideas?

The result should look like this:

[image: Merged result]

Comment: You are looking for *"multiple alpha blending"*. Search in this doc for slide with that title to see formula. http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/courses/15-463/2007_fall/Lectures/blending.pdf

Comment: You have shared 2 JPEG images without any alpha layer...

Comment: @MarkSetchell their formula for the composite intensity is wrong. use 128,0.5 and 128,0,5 in there, you'd expect it to be 128,0.75 but it's not. their formula results in premultiplied color without calling that out. the result _should_ have been not-premultiplied, like the inputs are. the result must be divided by the composite alpha to be un-premultiplied. you can try the mix with values like 64,0.25 and 192,0.333 (which add 1/4 of 64 + 3/4*1/3=1/4 of 192, leaving 2/4 transparent, i.e. expecting 128 at 1/2 opaque)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yes, your analysis looks good. If OP had supplied proper images I guess we would have applied the formula and found out...

Answer (score 0):

This will be a theoretical explanation because you haven't shared any code blocks yet. I will tell you the algorithm. In your two images, you must enclose your pixels in two separate arrays. You must also define a third array for the image to be created. You will compare the pixels of these two arrays as you wish and add the selected pixel to the array you defined for the image to be created. As a result, the new image will be created in a array format. It will only remain to show it.